# unable to select multiple options in react-select when we use it in loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

The table is looped with static data, with one select box to select multiple options in each row. So if I select any row option, then it shows no option. unable to select any one from remaining options and not even visible. showing no option. i need to select multiple options and save the entire table.

```
const [selectedOptions, setSelectedOptions] = useState([]);
  const objects = [
                   {'id':1, 'objectName':'Obj1'}
                   {'id':2, 'objectName':'Obj2'}
                   {'id':3, 'objectName':'Obj3'}
];
  const options = [
                   {'id':1, 'attrName':'atr1'}
                   {'id':2, 'attrName':'atr2'}
                   {'id':3, 'attrName':'atr3'}]
const handleSelectChange = (selectedOptions, index) => {
    console.log(selectedOptions, index)
  setSelectedOptions((prevSelectedOptions) => {
    const updatedOptions = [...prevSelectedOptions];
    updatedOptions[index] = selectedOptions;
    return updatedOptions;
  });
};
<Table variant='simple' color='gray.500' mb='24px' border={'1px'} borderColor={borderColor}>
          <Thead>
              <Tr >
                  <Th pe='10px' borderColor={borderColor}>
                    <Flex
                      justify='space-between'
                      align='center'
                      fontSize={{ sm: "10px", lg: "12px" }}
                      color='gray.400'>
                      Object
                    </Flex>
                  </Th>
                  <Th pe='10px' borderColor={borderColor}>
                    <Flex
                      justify='space-between'
                      align='center'
                      fontSize={{ sm: "10px", lg: "12px" }}
                      color='gray.400'>
                      Attributes
                    </Flex>
                  </Th>
                </Tr>
          </Thead>
          <Tbody >
            {
              objects.map((object,index)=>(
                <Tr key={object.id}>
                  <Td>{object["objectName"]}</Td>
                  <Td>
                  <Select key={object.id}
                    closeMenuOnSelect={false}
                    value={selectedOptions[index] || []}
                    onChange={(selectedOptions) =>
                      handleSelectChange(selectedOptions, index)
                    }
                    isMulti={true}
                    options={options}
                  />
                  </Td>

                </Tr>
              ))
            }
          </Tbody>
        </Table>
```

please help me to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the following code which can help you.

You can take `object.id` as key for the your state and set array as an value which can be used for your loop of objects with same options.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

import Select from "react-select";

export default () => {
  const objects = [
    { id: 1, objectName: "Obj1" },
    { id: 2, objectName: "Obj2" },
    { id: 3, objectName: "Obj3" }
  ];
  const options = [
    { value: 1, label: "atr1" },
    { value: 2, label: "atr2" },
    { value: 3, label: "atr3" }
  ];

  const [selectedOptions, setSelectedOptions] = useState({});

  return (
    <>
      <div>
        {objects.map((obj) => (
          <Select
            key={`obj_${obj.id}`}
            isMulti
            options={options}
            value={selectedOptions[obj.id] || []}
            onChange={(newVal) => {
              setSelectedOptions((prev) => ({
                ...prev,
                [obj.id]: newVal
              }));
            }}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
    </>
  );
};
```

Link to [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/codesandboxer-example-forked-txkq8d?file=/example.tsx:0-859)